# Windows CE - The wave header is corrupt

Tags: c#, windows-ce, motorola-emdk

I search all the Internet and yet didn't find a solution to my problem. I want just to play a sound from a resource, but it always, always gives me `The wave header is corrupt`. I saw several workarounds to solve this, like to set the `Stream.Position` to 0, nullify the `Stream` and after reload the sound, but it yet doesn't work. The piece of my code is this:

```
case TipoEvento.Erro:
    SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(); 
    Stream sound = new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.cow_single_cow_mooing);
    sound.Position = 0;
    player.Stream = null;
    player.Stream = sound;
    player.Play();
    break;
```

First i instantiate a `SoundPlayer`, then I read the bytes of the mp3 file I want to play, that is in `Properties.Resources`. Then I modify some attributes and finally go play. When I try to play, then the exception is throwed. How in the world can I play a sound in Windows CE? (.NET Framework 2.5, I have no `File.ReadAllBytes()`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: `SoundPlayer` only plays WAV files....not MP3.

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer(v=vs.110).aspx

Either convert your MP3 to a WAV file (which would result in a much bigger file)....or use the Windows Media Player control, or convert the MP3 data (using NAudio), etc.

- [Play MP3 using SoundPlayer after conversion to WAV using NAudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581349/play-mp3-using-soundplayer-after-conversion-to-wav-using-naudio)
- [Playing a MP3 file in a WinForm application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025626/playing-a-mp3-file-in-a-winform-application)

Comment: I used both. WAV files give me another exception. I can't remember now what it is, because I'm not on my development computer, but also gives me one. I'll ask the exception for it, then.